# Latest Android NDK (r21c)'s libbinder_ndk is missing several exported APIs

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, android-binder

I am interested in using the [AServiceManager_get/addService()](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r30:frameworks/native/libs/binder/ndk/service_manager.cpp;l=31-39) APIs that are made available via the NDK implementation of binder, `libbinder_ndk`.

The sources for this can be found here [for 10.0.0r30 - API29](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r30:frameworks/native/libs/binder/ndk/), and in your AOSP tree at:

```
$SDK/frameworks/native/libs/binder/ndk/
```

However, the `libbinder_ndk.so` bundled with [the latest r21c NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) does *not* have all of these APIs exported. Many are, but the get/add services endpoints are not available. The `libbinder_ndk.so` for API29 can be found at:

```
$NDK/platforms/android-29/$PLAT/usr/lib/libbinder_ndk.so
```

As well as the sysroot directories of each respective toolchain, but only for API29

```
$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST/sysroot/usr/lib/$PLAT/29/libbinder_ndk.so
```

But the symbols are of course available if you build the AOSP tree for this same release:

```
$ readelf --wide -s libbinder_ndk.so  | grep AService
   180: 000000000000e148   256 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 AServiceManager_addService@@LIBBINDER_NDK
   181: 000000000000e248   244 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 AServiceManager_checkService@@LIBBINDER_NDK
   224: 000000000000e33c   244 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 AServiceManager_getService@@LIBBINDER_NDK
```

In fact, a [search of the documentation](https://developer.android.com/s/results?q=aservicemanager) returns no results for these APIs, but the source [has been available since 2018-08-20](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/native/+/5a8fd1372f19fe19033d724eb5be643f8f3e535a:libs/binder/ndk/service_manager.cpp;drf=libs%2Fbinder%2Fndk%2FAServiceManager.cpp;drc=2e87adc8e708e24737a235ed8585602eb6e15a5c;bpv=0;bpt=0) according to the blame records.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Answer to your question below, but what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @DanAlbert Nothing explicitly required from the `libbinder_ndk`. I just intend to connect to a service and `transact` with it. You can do this from C++, but `libbinder_ndk` provided a C-based API (that just wrapped the C++ interfaces) that seemed nice for the job.

Answer (score 2):

The reason they are not exported is because they are not a part of the app API surface. They exist for vendor and APEX modules. Those domains do not have the same API permanence guarantees that apps do (read: they might disappear in any given release).

Comment: For what it's worth, when I had the same question, I filed this issue which (also) got an upstream reply: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160351035

Comment: Looks like that bug is waiting for feedback from you, btw.